# Plot3D axes not showing

Tags: plotting, linux

When I run:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I get no axes showing on my plot, i.e.
[image]

However when saving the plot as a PDF the axes are shown.

Does anyone have anyone idea on how to fix this? I would like to be able to see the axis in Mathematica notebook and the PDF file. I am using a clean install of  Mathematica 11.3 on Arch Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SW! What is the desired outcome? Would you like to have axis in the notebook or you would not like to have axis in the PDF?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the amibguity, I would like to have the axis in the notebook be visible, as well as the PDF file (edited my question for clarity).

Comment: Does `Axes->True` solve your problem?

Comment: @ctrl Just tried this, and it doesn't do anything; the plot remains the same as in the image.

Comment: If you apply `Rasterize` to the figure? You will lose some features, but it would at least be a workaround. Can we assume, that you have a "clean kernel" withuot any runtime or initialization time global graphics settings?

Comment: It might be a rendering issue on your Linux system. Try playing with [`RenderingOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenderingOptions.html).

Comment: You may have changed an option setting for `Plot3D`. Start with a fresh kernel to reset all of the options to their default.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I played around with rendering options and it seems to be that OpenGL was the problem. Switching to Mesa seemed to fix it. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that run into this problem, I was having problems with OpenGL rendering. Instead of running `mathematica` in the shell, running `mathematica -mesa` seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I get the axes in v. 11.3.0.0.

[image]

Nevertheless, you might add `Boxed->True`

Comment: I have added `Boxed -> True` but this didn't do anything. Thanks anyway.